# Не могу установить ubuntu 16.04. Ошибка: "Cannot display this video mode change computer display input to 1920x1080 60hz"

Tags: ubuntu, экран

Не могу поставить ubuntu 16.04. Проблема в том, что после выбора языка установки, экран становится черным и появляется надпись  "Cannot display this video mode change computer display input to 1920x1080 60hz". Но вот как и где это сделать? 
Такая же проблема с установкой кубунты 16.04.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/853442/cannot-install-ubuntu-16-04-1-video-mode-problem

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо в меню GRUB нажать <kbd>e</kbd> и в строку, которая начинается как `linux...` добавить `nomodeset` перед `quiet splash`.